# Hough transform to determine lines and their width

Tags: image-processing, opencv, hough-transform

Are there any implementations or papers that modify the Hough transform to detect the width of line segments? Hough space maxima can be used to determine potential lines, and line segments are groups of pixels that are on the line for sufficient intervals. After doing that, I'm trying to determine the width of each line segment.

All I've been able to find thus far is this poster:
http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~lyu/staff/SongJQ/poster_47_song_j.pdf

Comment: i think the amount in accumulator of Hough transform is aproximate width of a line.

for example: if the line detected with hough transform. The accumulator have a max that represent this line. So this max is approximate the width of this line. Because is the amount of pixel that make la recta.

Comment: The accumulator's value is the number of points for which their polar coordinate is (r, theta). This means that the accumulator's value is the number of points on the line, not the width of the line.

Comment: Probably better on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: Dmi. If you have the number of points that is the number of pixel of line. So, with the number of pixel and angle i can use basic geometric rules to get width or not?

Comment: Yes, see the paper referred to in the answer that I accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending if you are willing to spend some money, there is a package called Halcon that has the kind of things you are after.

For example http://www.mvtec.com/download/reference/lines_gauss.html (that's not a Hough transform, but the main package does have those as well).

I used Google to find a paper called "Extraction of Curved Lines from Images" which mentions line width (I can't get the link to work either).

Comment: I use a hough transform to determine where lines probably are, and then I trace line segments to figure out which parts of the line are probably line segments, just to narrow things down for a line classifier. Unfortunately, I don't have money to purchase a commercial library, I was hoping for something either open-source or information in the public domain.

Clicking on your paper link leads to a page that says "No document with DOI "10.1.1.42.7963""

Comment: Hi, I put the title in the text - the clickable link didn't work, it only seemed to work from the Google results page.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks. It suggests basically following a Bresenham line out from the points on the detected line to determine how far until it hits the boundary of the image's line. Here is the pdf in case anyone reads this question in the future: http://ias.informatik.tu-muenchen.de/_media/people/steger/publications/1996/icpr-96-steger.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If you have a binary mask for each line segment could you possibly take the maximum of the [distance transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_transform) on that line segment? It should tell you how far away the center of the line is from the edge, the width should be `2*max(distanceTranform(segment)) - 1` for odd widths and `2*max(distanceTranform(segment))` for even widths.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has an implementation of this method [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=distance#cv2.distanceTransform). They also have [HoughLinesP](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghlines#void%20HoughLinesP%28InputArray%20image,%20OutputArray%20lines,%20double%20rho,%20double%20theta,%20int%20threshold,%20double%20minLineLength,%20double%20maxLineGap%29) to detect line segments, but sounds like you already have that worked out.

Comment: Interesting, I will take a look at distance transforms, thanks. I do not have a binary mask for each line segment in the image, only the start and end points that make up a line in the image with no width information. Some lines intersect with each other and with background objects, so I'm not sure how well a distance transform would work.

I think I will take a look at OpenCV's implementation. What I did is similar to OpenCV's HoughLines, but then I extract line segments along the line, which are then verified (for gaps and minimum length) like HoughLinesP.